# Добавить в пользователя логи

Tags: apache, freebsd

Создал пользователя, создал ftp. Сайт с папки грузится (лежит в home пользователя).

Вопрос, как добавить в пользователя (чтобы был доступ по ftp), также файлы логов апача и т.д. (то что ему нужно для работы).

Answer (score 1):

логичнее всего настроить *http*-сервер на сохранение логов для выбранного сайта в домашнем каталоге того же пользователя, у которого в домашнем каталоге хранится и *docroot* самого сайта.

довольно часто встрачающаяся практика:

```
# mkdir /домашний/каталог/пользователя/{logs,www}
```

в каталоге `logs` сохраняются логи сайта, в каталоге `www` — *docroot* сайта.

**дополнение**

местоположение (и количество подробностей) лог-файлов можно указывать в соответствующем *virtualhost*-е:

- [директива customlog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog)
- [директива errorlog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog)
- [директива accesslog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog)
- [примеры блоков virtualhost](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts)